# longとdoubleでsqrtの戻り値が異なる

Tags: c, 浮動小数点数

`<math.h>` の `sqrt` 関数について質問です。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    long n = 100000000;
    long l = 94941695;
    double d = 94941695;
    printf("sqrt [long]  : %.10f\n", sqrt(n * n - l * l));
    printf("sqrt [double]: %.10f\n", sqrt(n * n - d * d));
}
```

を実行すると、次の結果が得られました:

```
$ ./a.out
sqrt [long]  : 31401823.9999999851
sqrt [double]: 31401824.0000000000
```

何故結果が異なるのでしょうか。
なお、10 ^ 16 - 94941695 ^ 2 = 986074550526975で、
　　√(986074550526975) = 3.14018239999999840... × 10 ^ 7
でした。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

演算精度のせいで、`sqrt(n * n - l * l)`に与えられる引数の値と`sqrt(n * n - d * d)`に与えられる引数の値が異なるためです。

(なお、`long`の表す桁数は処理系によって異なりますが、ここでは出力例から、`long`は64ビット整数型を表すものとします。)

`n * n - l * l`を引数とする場合、`n`および`l`は共に`long`型であり、また、途中計算の`n * n`と`l * l`の結果も`long`型の範囲に収まるため、計算結果は正確に`long`型の`986074550526975`となり、その値が暗黙の型変換で`double`に変換された後に`sqrt`が呼ばれます。

それに対して、`n * n - d * d`を引数とする場合、`n * n`は一旦`long`で計算され、正確に`long`型の`10000000000000000`となりますが、引き算の相手の`d * d`は`double`型なので、その値は`double`型に変換されます。

ここで肝心なのは、`double`型の精度は10進換算で15〜16桁であり、`10000000000000000`も`94941695 * 94941695`の計算結果として期待される`9013925449473025`もその限界を超えているため、**`double`ではそれらの値を正確には表せない** のです。

言葉による説明だけは分かりにくいので、途中結果を見てみましょう。

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    long n = 100000000;
    long l = 94941695;
    double d = 94941695;
    printf("n * n [long] : %ld\n", n * n);
    printf("l * l [long] : %ld\n", l * l);
    printf("n * n - l * l: %.10f\n", (double)(n * n - l * l));
    printf("sqrt [long]  : %.10f\n", sqrt(n * n - l * l));
    printf("n * n[double]: %.10f\n", (double)(n * n));
    printf("d * d[double]: %.10f\n", d * d);
    printf("n * n - d * d: %.10f\n", (double)(n * n - d * d));
    printf("sqrt [double]: %.10f\n", sqrt(n * n - d * d));
    return 0;
}
```

結果(`<-`以下は注釈):

```
n * n [long] : 10000000000000000
l * l [long] : 9013925449473025
n * n - l * l: 986074550526975.0000000000
sqrt [long]  : 31401823.9999999851
n * n[double]: 10000000000000000.0000000000  <- `print`で表示した結果は正しく見えるが1の位まで正確には表現できない
d * d[double]: 9013925449473024.0000000000   <- `print`で表示した結果にも誤差が表れている
n * n - d * d: 986074550526976.0000000000    <- `986074550526975`じゃない!
sqrt [double]: 31401824.0000000000
```

(`double`は内部では2進数で表現されているので、10進数との変換の際に誤差が入ったり、逆に誤差が相殺されて見掛け上正しい値に見えてしまうことがあるので、10進表記で全てを理解しようとするのには無理があるんですが、ここでは見掛けにはっきり違いが表れているので詳細には立ち入らないことにします。)

と言うわけで、`double`で計算を行う場合、途中計算まで含めて「`double`の精度で正しく表せるかどうか」を気にしないと、整数で正確な計算をしたのと同じ結果にはならないことに注意しないといけません。

Comment: 細かいですが、10,000,000,000,000,000=‭23'86F2'6FC1'0000‬については下16bitが0なので必要精度40bitで、これ自体はdoubleで正確に表せます。

Comment: @sayuri さん、「正確に」と言う言葉の問題かもしれませんが、`10000000000000000`と`10000000000000001`との違いを表現できないのに「正確に表せます」と言ってしまうのには問題があるように思われます。ただそれを言うなら「誤差を含む」と言う言い方も良くありませんね。そこは訂正します。

Comment: @OOPer さん、そのように正確さを定義すると、たとえば 0 と 0.00000000...0001 の違いを表現できないことを理由に「0 を正確に表せない」ことになってしまいませんか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、0.00000000...0001を問題にする用途なら「0 を正確に表せない」と言うのはその通りですよ。今は整数演算との誤差の話をしているので、1の位まで正確に計算結果に表せるかどうかが問題にされていると考えるべきです。

Comment: うーん、あまり納得できていません。おそらく「値を正確に表せない」という部分にひっかかっているのだと思います。値それ自体は正確に表せているものの、何かしら演算をすると（演算相手が整数でも）正確じゃなくなる場合があるという状況を的確に表現できていないと感じています。「double ではこの値と演算すると誤差が出る可能性があります」くらいなら分かります。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、あなたが「的確に表現」できていないと思うのであれば、あなたご自身の回答の中でそれを表現していただければ良いことだと思います。コメントはあなたの感じ方について議論する場所ではありません。

Comment: 「`10000000000000001`を正確に表現できない」は正しいです。そして`10000000000000001`を正確に表現できない以上、`10000000000000001`と`X`との違いを表現できないのは当然です。それをもって`10000000000000000`を正確に表現できないというのは明確な誤りです。

Comment: @OOPer さん、すいません、私の書き方が悪くて、値自体は正確に表せているというのは感じ方の問題ではなく事実です。その上でどういう書き方なら誤解を少なくできそうか、という話をしているつもりでした。他の表現も考えてみたのですが、たとえば「分解能が足りていない」という言い方はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @sayuri さん、すいませんが、「明確な誤り」と主張されるのであれば、「正確に表現」と言うのがあなたの言う通りの意味でしか使われていないことを示し明確な根拠をいただけるでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、sayuriさんにもお聞きしたのと同じですが、「事実です」と言うのならその根拠をお示しください。お二人とも「浮動小数点数は仮数部を無限にゼロ拡張した値を正確に表現している、と言うことを前提に話をしておられるように思います。

Comment: @OOPer さん、なるほど、最下位ビットより下のビットが 0 で固定されているか unspecified なのかによって変わってしまうということですね。であればこれは 0 で固定でよくて、たとえば IEEE 754 に規定されている convertToDecimalCharacter の仕様にそう書かれています。「ひとつの浮動小数点数が表しているのはひとつの小数ではなく小数の範囲なのだ」というのはあくまで丸めまで含めてビット列の意味を考えている場合の話で、今回の例だと 10^16 に対して long -> double も double -> long も誤差無しで行える以上、10^16 という値を正確に表現できていると言う他無いでしょう。言い換えると、浮動小数点数側では「有効数字が足りていなくて分解能が 1 より大きい」という意味で不確かさが大きいというのは正しいですが、今回のように long という表現と double という表現の間の変換をする部分においては問題になりません。（このような状況を短く説明するのは難しいですね……。）

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、そこに書かれたことがなぜ「正確に表現できていると言う他無い」ことになるのか、全く論理が通っていません。「これが成り立てば正確に表現できていると言って良い」と言うのを大前提にしているからそのような結果が出てくるのでしょう。「ひとつの浮動小数点数が表しているのはひとつの小数ではなく実数(修正しました)の範囲なのだ」と言う見方をご存じならば、浮動小数点数自体は何かの値を「正確に」表現することはあり得ず、問題領域に十分な精度を持っているかどうかが決定的に重要になってくるのはお分かりいただけるように思うのですが。あなたが使われている意味で「正確な」と言う言葉を使われる方がいるのは十分理解できますが、本当に「他無い」のかどうか十分に検討されてはいないように思われます。

Answer (score 1):

sqrt ではなく、その前段の `n * n - d * d` の時点で丸め誤差が生まれています。

```
printf("%.10f\n", double(n * n - l * l));
printf("%.10f\n", n * n - d * d);
```

を実行すると

```
986074550526975.0000000000
986074550526976.0000000000
```

と出力され、下 1 桁が異なります。

IEEE 754 の倍精度では、2 進数で 53 桁まで情報を保持することができます（一番上の整数部分の桁を含む）。これは 10 進数だと約 15.95 桁で、今 17 桁 ひく 16 桁の計算をしようとしているのでどこかで丸めが起きる可能性があります。

---

では、ちゃんとビット表現まで確認してみましょう。実は `d * d` の時点で丸め誤差が起きています。簡単に言うと、

```
long n = 100000000;
long l = 94941695;
double d = 94941695;
printf("%ld\n", l * l);
printf("%.10f\n", d * d);
```

は

```
9013925449473025
9013925449473024.0000000000
```

と出力します。この部分をビット表現で確認すると、

```
// 上は long、下は double です。double は仮数部だけ見てください。
l * l =    0000000000100000000001100001111000010000011100101001110000000001
d * d = 0 10000110100 0000000000110000111100001000001110010100111000000000
//                   ↑ この桁から比較してください。
//        ↑ 指数部
//      ↑ 符号部
```

というように一番下の 1 が落ちてしまっていることが分かります。

このビット表現は下のプログラムで確かめました。

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    double d;
    long l;
} value;

void print_binary(long n, int digit)
{
    if (digit <= 64) {
        print_binary(n >> 1, digit + 1);

        printf((n & 1) ? "1" : "0");
        if (digit == 53 || digit == 64) {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    return;
}

void print_binary_long(long l) {
    print_binary(l, 1);
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void print_binary_double(double d) {
    value v;
    v.d = d;
    print_binary(v.l, 1);
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    long l = 94941695;
    double d = 94941695;

    printf("l2 =  ");
    print_binary_long(l * l);

    printf("d2 = ");
    print_binary_double(d * d);

    return 0;
}
```